# Sql to select the prerequisite of a certain course

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

I have a table that has courses details as follows:

[image: Courses Table]

And, in the Windows, form I placed a textBox and a button, when a student writes the name of the course to see the prerequisite requirement of that course as follows:

[image: Windows Form]

So I tried using the following code:

```
conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "select Name from Courses where (Name = '" + textBox2.Text + "') and  Preq = Code";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt); 
        dataGridView3.DataSource = dt;
        conn.Close();
        textBox2.Text = "";
```

However, the code gives me the name column without any data as follows:

[image: Result of my Code]

Also, is there a way to show a message when the course does not have any requirement such as " this course has no prerequisite requirement " something like that?

Comment: In all rows of your table, the `Preq` and `Code` columns are not equal. Therefore, the `Preq = Code` condition is never met.

Comment: Remove `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` call. It absolutely useless.

Comment: Also use parameters instead of string concatenation in sql query.

Comment: To "show a message", you can get the number of rows affected via `int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 0):

your query is wrong , the below query returns the list of courses that are requirement for the given course name :

```
select Name from Courses 
where code IN ( select PREQ from Courses where 
Name = '" + textBox2.Text + "')
```

also It would be easier to handle showing a message in your c# code to show if there is no preq.you can checking if dt is null or not .